# How to modify Subsubsection Header (apa6.cls)?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, apa6

I am using the `apa6.cls` for my document and need a different format of the section headers. I managed to modify the section and subsection header to match my criteria (see below).

But the `\subsubsection` is still indented and followed by a dot, which I'd like to modify:

> *Stimulusmaterial.*

(with indention)

In the end, the Subsubsection header should look like

> *Stimulusmaterial*

(without indention)

```
\documentclass[ngerman,man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\section{\normalfont{Methode}}
\subsection*{\centering\normalfont\textit{Material}}
\subsubsection{\normalfont\textit{Stimulusmaterial}}
\end{document}
```

As far as I tried, `\noindent` did'nt work and i have no idea how to remove the dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really don't know why you want to use the `apa6.cls` and, most of all, try to change the appearance of the section titles. The class is intended for submissions and not for real typesetting: the format it uses is typographically ugly.

Anyway, here's how you can change the appearance according to your wishes.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,man,12pt,a4paper,noextraspace,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}
  {\z@}
  {\b@level@one@skip}
  {\e@level@one@skip}
  {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}
  {\z@}
  {\b@level@two@skip}
  {\e@level@two@skip}
  {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
  {\z@}
  {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{X}
\author{Y}
\maketitle

\section{Methode}

\subsection{Material}

\subsubsection{Stimulus material}

Some text following.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The Prof in my psychology course wants us to write our M.Sc. thesis in apa manuscript style, but the specific requirements given differed a bit from the output of the apa6.cls, e. g. concerning the section headers. I considered it easier to build on this .cls though, than adapting the usual latex article class. At least for me as a beginner. The uglyness of the resulting format is nothing I can influence. Anyway, thank you very much, it works very well!

Comment: @entne I am very sorry for your thesis. :( You can always typeset a different version for your enjoyment using a *real* class. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to redefine the macro `\addperi`, which sets the period for `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph`. Give the below command to change the period for all cases:

```
\renewcommand*{\addperi}[1]{#1}
```

This will also remove dot after paragraph heading.

---

Otherwise you need to rename `\addperi` command and need to redefine the `\subsubsection` macro itself like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\newaddperi}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {0\baselineskip \@plus 0.2ex \@minus 0.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\newaddperi}}
\makeatother
```

HTH

Comment: BTW: I can't find the indentation of C level head.

Comment: I am new to LateX, so I have to inquire and add a few things: The paragraph heading is also fine as it is, we are only talking about subsubsection. So I tried your second redefinition. Am I right that this hast to be in the preamble? It removes the dot, but subsubsection is still indented. When I replace `\parindent` with `\noindent`, I get several errors concerning my subsubsection and paragraph headings.

Comment: OK. Now got it. Its now corrected.