# Tabular with dotfill and mbox

Tags: tables

I want to have the space between "List of Tables" and the page numbers filled with dots matching `{\cftdotfill{1.5}}` and including the option to define `\makebox[1.9em]`

How is this done?

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{.45\textwidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    \raggedright
    List of Tables &  ix
\end{tabular*}
```

Work Example:

```
\documentclass[doc,12pt]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=american]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage[all]{nowidow} 
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,caption} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tocloft}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{underscore}
\doublespacing{}
\raggedbottom{} 
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont} 
\shorttitle{short title} 
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

% ------------ Header Patches  ------------
% source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125537/how-to-modify-subsubsection-header-apa6-cls?rq=1
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection {section}{1}
    {\z@}
    {\b@level@one@skip}
    {\e@level@one@skip}
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}}

\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}
    {\z@}
    {\b@level@two@skip}
    {\e@level@two@skip}
    {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\textbf}}

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
    {\z@}
    {\b@level@three@skip}
    {\e@level@three@skip}
    {\hspace*{-0.5in}\normalfont\normalsize\textbf}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\paragraph}% <cmd> 
{\bfseries\itshape}% <search> 
{\bfseries}% <replace> 
{}{}% <success><failure>

\setlist [itemize,enumerate]{leftmargin=0.5in,noitemsep, topsep=0pt} 
%sets margin for lists, default seems to be 2em (?), removes spaces between listed items

%--------------------------------------- PREFIX TABLE

\newcommand\myleaders{\cftdotfill{1.5}} % same as in TOC!
\def\mypara#1#2{\noindent#1\myleaders\makebox[1.9em][r]{#2}}

%--------------------------------------- End PREFIX TABLE

%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Begin TOC Format Definitions 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace ”english” with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {}} %You can leave this empty
\renewcommand\contentsname{\MakeUppercase{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfill\normalfont\mdseries}

\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{1.5}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecleader{\cftdotfill{1.5}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecleader{\cftdotfill{1.5}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand\cftbeforesecskip{6pt} 
\renewcommand\cftbeforesubsecskip{-6pt}
\renewcommand\cftbeforesubsubsecskip{-6pt}
\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{1em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{3em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{6em}{2.5em}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}

\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{0in}
%------   Hide the LFT and LOT Headers  -------------------------------
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace ”english” with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}% turnes default name of
    {}} %You can leave this empty
\addto\captionsenglish{% Replace ”english” with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}%
    {}} %You can leave this empty% turnes default name of
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% END TOC Format Definitions 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Begin of Table Settings 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\IE}[1][1]{% indent entry
    \hspace{#1em}\ignorespaces}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
% END of Table Settings 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Turn on the style from the fancyhdr package
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Clear the header and footer
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
% Set the position of the footer to be the page number L, C, R
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%---------------------------------------------------------------


%--Begin tocloft implementation ---------------------------------------
\begin{center}
TABLE OF CONTENTS
\end{center}
\noindent

%--Begin PREFIX implementation ---------------------------------------

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{.45\textwidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    \raggedright
    List of Tables &  ix
\end{tabular*}

\mypara{List of Tables}{ix}

\mypara{List of Figures}{ix}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're building a table of contents on your own. Are you sure you want to do that instead of using a package for it?

Comment: I am using "\usepackage{tocloft}", but can't get it to work with "\def\mypara#1#2{\noindent#1\myleaders\makebox[1.9em][r]{#2}}" and "\mypara{List of Tables}{ix}" together with "\mypara{List of Figures}{ix}". The No. ix is not aligned to the right.

Comment: Can you please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Also you can mark inline code in comments by surrounding it with `\``.

Comment: ok, I added the work example to my original post.

Comment: Do you know the `\tableofcontents` macro?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
\newcommand\myleaders{\cftdotfill{1.5}} 
\def\mypara#1#2{\noindent#1\myleaders\makebox[1.7em][r]{#2}}
```

! It makes a difference to have a blank line or `\\` between the commands !

```
%--Begin PREFIX implementation -------------------------------------
\mypara{List of Tables}{ix} \\
\mypara{List of Figures}{ix} \\
\vspace*{0.7em} 
%--End PREFIX implementation ---------------------------------------
```